# When was the German word Homeoffice coined?

Tags: etymology, pseudo-anglicism

I heard the word Homeoffice first around 2010. It is not directly borrowed from English, since English speaking countries use constructions like "work from home".

There is also the older German word Telearbeit which is still in use but usually only applied to situations where someone is using a complete room in their flat as an office, not just a desk in the living room with a notebook computer.

Where and when was the word Homeoffice created?

Comment: You can find "home office" meaning a place to work from home in Wiktionary. Wiktionary also says that German Homeoffice is borrowed from English. I think you're talking about Homeoffice in the sense of telecommuting, and you're correct that this doesn't exist in English. It seems that the word was originally borrowed from English, but gained a new meaning in German. In any case, it would help to include a sentence for context so people can be sure which meaning you're referring to.

Comment: I don't know why you rule out borrowing from English. "home office" is a perfectly common term in English. See e.g., [1](https://www.nbc.com/today/video/upgrade-your-home-office-with-these-gadgets/4249312) [2](https://www.nbc.com/the-tonight-show/video/jon-hamm-gives-jimmy-a-tour-of-his-home-office-hints-at-mad-men-reunion/4161849) [3](https://edition.cnn.com/2021/08/31/cnn-underscored/best-work-from-home-office-essentials) [4](https://www.apple.com/uk/shop/accessories/all/home-office) [5](https://www.wired.com/story/work-from-home-home-office-gear-guide/), I could go on.

Comment: Mostly american links because if you restrict search to UK you mostly get stuff about the government branch, but as a native British English speaker I can assure you "home office" is in regular usage there too.

Comment: @ChrisH In English, I always read something like "work from home", "remote work" etc. I am right that home office in English means that you have an actual room in your flat for working from home? Not just working from home from some desk or your kitchen table? So maybe home office was borrowed from English but changed meaning.

Comment: @JFabianMeier I'd argue that "das Homeoffice" refers to an [Arbeitszimmer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A4usliches_Arbeitszimmer) as well. Only if transferring the term to mean the activity of working from there (e.g. "er macht heute home office"), i.e. Heimarbeit or Telearbeit, it would be relaxed to also include working from the couch in your living room, if your job allows that.

Comment: @JFabianMeier if used as a noun about a space, then I'd interpret it as _most likely_ a specific dedicated space (though not necessarily a whole room, it could certainly be a desk in a room with some other purpose). But as Bergi says, I'd say the same for German. Used more generically, "remote work" or "work from home" might be more common but a company certainly wouldn't raise any eyebrows by having a "home office policy". Even if it weren't, the meaning shift would only be from "working from a dedicated office room in my home" to "working from my home", which seems minimal to say the least.

Comment: @ChrisH [this is confusing isn't it] in (my) British English a "Home Office" is a place - a room, the dining table, or a garden shed, for example - an *Arbeitszimmer* (synonym in English "study" or just "office" where it clearly doesn't mean a building you commute to).  It's not an activity.  Germans I've discussed this with in English talk about "doing home office" which is a little different to anything I've heard in native English.  It's not purely a German thing - a Czech colleague uses it as well, even abbreviating it to "H/O" in a written context where "WFH" is common.

Comment: ... Checking our intranet, policies are about "working off campus", "working from home" etc.  and not "home office", which doesn't even appear in the guidance about setting up a workspace.  But there's a reason in British English - the Home Office is the government body that in other countries might be the Interior Ministry - a set phrase with a different meaning would tend to reduce adoption

Comment: @ChrisH (yes, this is confusing) yeah, I agree that it's not an activity. I certainly wouldn't "do home office" the way I'd *mache Homeoffice*, although "I'm in home office" sounds fine to me. Admittedly that could be the influence of 13 years and counting in Germany. If OP means "home office" specifically *as an activity* then it didn't quite come across to me - I understood the claim as "home office" not existing in English at all (within a work context, not government), even as the noun referring to an office at home - although looking back I suspect you're right.

Comment: @ChrisH: It should be noted that even when I (native German speaker) say "Ich bin heute im Home Office.", I definitely do not think of it as a room, or any particular space or location. (And in practice, it can mean that I sit at home at in our computer room just as much as it might mean that I'm using my notebook somewhere on a train.) Conceptually, it rather feels like an activity/working mode, same as in "Ich bin jetzt in Elternzeit."

Comment: @ChrisH I wouldn't use "I'm in home office" without "my".  But my working from home isn't always office work (which I don't think affects how I use the terminology, but perhaps): it sometimes involves working on electronics (for which my home desk is also my lab bench) or even making some quick mechanical  modifications at the workbench in the garage.  I'm not sure whether the OP  did mean it specifically as an activity or not.  I think the contrast with "working from home" implies that, while your examples tend towards the location meaning

Comment: Note that German regularily "borrows" words from English that are unknown in actual spoken English. "Handy" (mobile phone / smartphone) is the most common example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The term was most likely coined between **1990** and **1994**.

### First Occurrences: 1994

When looking at the first occurrences of the term, it won't be possible to be certain about the very earliest occurrences for methodical reasons.

With this method, we will always talk about an upper boundary of the actual first use of the word. Special attention has to be paid to the fact that the word "home office" exists in English (but with the meaning of "ministery of the interior" in British English, and "headquarters", "main office" in American English).

The first ever mentioning of the word in a German newspaper (according to DWDS-Wortverlaufskurve for German newspapers <sup>[[1](https://www.dwds.de/r/plot/?view=3&corpus=zeitungenxl&norm=date%2Bclass&smooth=spline&genres=0&grand=1&slice=1&prune=0&window=3&wbase=0&logavg=0&logscale=0&xrange=1946%3A2024&q1=%7B%27Homeoffice%27%2C%27Home-Office%27%2C%27Home%20Office%27%7D)]</sup>) seems to be 1994. The first occurrence in the searchable corpus <sup>[[2](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=Homeoffice&corpus=dwdsxl&date-start=1897&date-end=2020&sc=adg&sc=bz&sc=blogs&sc=bundestag&sc=ddr&sc=tsp&sc=kern&sc=kern21&sc=gesetze&sc=spk&sc=politische_reden&sc=untertitel&sc=wikibooks&sc=wikipedia&sc=wikivoyage&format=full&sort=date_asc&limit=10)], [[3](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=Home-Office&corpus=dwdsxl&date-start=1897&date-end=2020&sc=adg&sc=bz&sc=blogs&sc=bundestag&sc=ddr&sc=tsp&sc=kern&sc=kern21&sc=gesetze&sc=spk&sc=politische_reden&sc=untertitel&sc=wikibooks&sc=wikipedia&sc=wikivoyage&format=full&sort=date_asc&limit=10)]</sup> of DWDS is from 1997, though (in an article from *Die ZEIT*), in the spelling *Home-Office*. Browsing through the first hits gives me the impression that the term mostly referred to the situation of freelancers or self-employed people working with a computer.

### Likely Lower Boundary: 1990

For a lower boundary, we have to use other methods, which might not yield perfectly accurate results, but still give us some hints for a more informed guess.

It seems reasonable to assume that the word *Home Office* would be influenced by a broadening of meaning of the word *Office* (both in English and German) from "administrative department", "agency", "Amt", "Amtsstube" to also include the meaning "workplace for white-collar jobs".

Looking into the occurrences of *Office* in the DWDS corpus gives us some hints: DWDS corpus reaches back only to 1897, but looking beyond that is not of interest for the question at hand anyways. (The term and its variations have been around for a long time, as English imported it from French, which took it from Latin *officium*, but I don't think it is relevant for the question of *Home Office*.)

Within this time frame, the term *Office* has basically always been in use in German, with varying frequency.<sup>[[4](https://www.dwds.de/r/plot/?view=1&corpus=dwdsxl&norm=date%2Bclass&smooth=spline&genres=0&grand=1&slice=1&prune=0&window=0&wbase=0&logavg=0&logscale=0&xrange=1900%3A2024&q1=Office)]</sup> In the beginning, *Office* was used with feminine gender in German.  (One of the first hits in the DWDS corpus is Karl May, who peppered in foreign language expressions into his texts as a stylistic device, in order to make the narrator sound widely-traveled. He uses feminine gender.)

Browsing through the hits in DWDS corpus around the 1990's, the most frequent occurrence of the term *Office* in German  (besides non-translated occurrences of foreign language terms such as *Oval Office*, *Office du Tourisme*, *Central Office*, and so on), relate to *Microsoft Office* a suite of computer programs (most notably for text editing, spreadsheet calculations and presentations), accompanied by a couple of competitors with similar names (*Corel Office*, *Star Office*). This is the *Office* with the meaning we are interested in. Microsoft Office was first released in 1990.<sup>[[5](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Microsoft_Office#Version_history)]</sup>

I would reckon that the name of these software products paved the way for the term *Home Office*, making 1990 a likely lower boundary for the coining of *Home Office*. This theory involves some amount of speculation, but it is quite convincing to me, as both words correlate to a new way of working involving the computer. It seems plausible to me that this revolution of the work style, the emergence of a new concept of work sparked a desire for a new word and that the existence of the very prominent *Office* computer program would make German speakers favor the anglicism *Home Office* over creating new German words such as **Heimbüro* (which does not exist).

Comment: That fits with my experience as German "Homeoffice" until the late aughts meant that your employer would endow you with a (tower) PC, monitor (CRT, later LCD), keyboard, mouse etc. and a WAN/VPN connection to the company network. It was a huge affair and costly as well so it was usually done only for a limited number of employees. But I also remember that term being used ca. 2000 when I was working in 2nd level IT support for an insurance company.
These days, "im Homeoffice sein / arbeiten" (to be in or to work from "Homeoffice") just means you open up your company laptop, maybe on the sofa.